# Need help in adding admob in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, admob

I have my web based app using html and css .I build using phone gap and it works well,When i try to integrate admob in my app it shows AdActivity is missing in manifest file.I have searched and didn't found any answers.Kindly help!.

This is my mainactivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
doAdmob();
}
}, 1000);
}
private void doAdmob() {   
// Create the adView
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-000000000000000000000000");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
// Lookup your LinearLayout - get the super.root
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);
// This centers the ads in landscape mode.        
layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}  
}
```

This is my android manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


<application 
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
<intent-filter>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        />


</application>
```

Kindly help...........

Comment: have you checked [this](https://github.com/lukeheuer/PhoneGap-Android-Native-AdMob) and if you are using cordova cli use [cordova-plugin-admob](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phonegap you can try to build the app in each specific platform and then integrate admob by modifying the code, which it seems that it is what you are trying to do. You will have to do it for each platform you want to support and also you'll have to write the native code for each platform as well. **I recommend you to use a plugin**, with which you'll have already done the native and manifest integration.

If you want to modify the native code, you can [see here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/) how to integrate admob in android and ios.

If you decide to use a plugin, I recommend the one that I'm maintaining: [admob-google-cordova](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)

It is very easy to integrate:

```
cordova plugin add com.admob.google
```

Or if you want to use phonegap cli:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.git
```

And to use it, in javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-8440343014846849/3119840614",
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-8440343014846849/4596573817"
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestIntertitial();
}
```

(Replace the code with your publisher id's) Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

The easiest and fastest way is to use `cordova plugin add com.admob.google` from command line. Anyway I leave here the instructions to add support in Eclipse:

- Download the plugin from [Github](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/archive/master.zip) or via command line: `git clone https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.git`
- Uncompress the donwloaded plugin
- Copy `src/android/*.java` into `YourProjectFolder/platforms/android/src/com/appfeel/cordova/admob/`
- Copy `src/android/res/values/admob.xml` into `YourProjectFolder/platforms/android/res/values/android.xml`
- [Add support for android-support-v4](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res)
- [Add support for google-play-services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)
- Open your manifest file and add the following under `<application...>` tag:

Code:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: Hi miquel thanks for your answer.I am new to android development,i dont know how to add the plugin of phonegap in eclipse project.Can you help in sort this?

Comment: @ZaffarKhan I edited the response with instructions. Please let me know if it works for you